# Is there a way to mute user(s)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

If someone or some group of people are abusing the @user handles and asking trolling questions. Is there some way to mute the person and prevent notification from the specific user's usage of @ handle to notify me?

Answer (score 6):

1. Ignore in chat
2. Don't comment
3. Flag their comments
4. After a while, flag a comment with a custom message explaining the trolling

Comment: 5. Wait patiently for moderators to step in.

Comment: @Oded no, must. have. now!

Comment: 2.5 ask a room owner to own their boots

Comment: 6. PROFIIIIIIT!!!!!!!